# Can a function have multiple limits?

Tags: real-analysis

Is this proposition true?

If $A$ is the limit of function, when $x$ approach to $y$, according to the definition of limit by Cauchy, the number which have the difference with $A$ is smaller than any positive real number is also the limit.

Comment: Limits of sequences and functions on the real number line, if they exist as finite values, are unique. It is a good exercise to try to prove this.

Comment: Of course it's true. However, there are no such numbers other than $A$ itself.

Comment: What do you mean by "a number which have the difference with  is smaller than any positive real number is also the limit"?

Comment: "the number which have the difference with A is smaller than any positive real number"  That number is A, itself.

Comment: "What do you mean by "a number which have the difference with  is smaller than any positive real number is also the limit"?"  Makes perfect sense to me.  If $\lim_{x\to y} f(x) = A$ and $|A - B| < \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon$ then $\lim_{x\to y} f(x) = B$ as well. .... However if $|A-B| < \epsilon;\forall \epsilon$ then .... well, something rather blatant about how $A$ and $B$ are related....

Comment: What does this have to do with "multiple" limits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\lim_{x\to y} f(x) = A$ and if $|A-B|< \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$ then the following two statements are true.

1)  $\lim_{x \to y} f(x) = B$

And

2)  $A = B$.

1) Proof:

For any $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta$ so that if $|x -y| < \delta$ then $|f(x)- A| < \frac \epsilon2$ so $|f(x) - B| \le |f(x) -A| + |A-B| < \frac \epsilon 2 +\frac \epsilon 2$ so $\lim_{x\to y} f(x) = B$.

2) Proof:   If $A \ne B$ then $|A-B| > 0$ and Let $\epsilon = |A-B| > 0$ then $|A-B| = \epsilon$ and that is a contradiction.

Which makes the first proof rather obsolete, because $|f(x) -A| + |A-B| = |f(x)-A| + 0 = |f(x) - A| = |f(x) - B|$.

And to answer your question,

No, if a function has a limit $x \to y$, the limit can only have one value.

Because if $\lim_{x\to y} f(x) = A$ and $\lim_{x\to y} f(x) = B$ then $A = B$.